google sheet merge two column into one column with prefix words
I'm using Google Sheets and looking for an arrayformula()? that able to merge two column into one .
let's say I have the following two columns:



A
B




02543980
420000B4


02543994
420000B4


025439B0
E8079F1A



I'm hoping to write a  formula to make a  list like this, where the two columns are combined, and then repeat the lists infinitely (drag down):



C




ADR $02543980


OVERWRITE 42 00 00 B4


ADR $02543994


OVERWRITE 42 00 00 B4


ADR $025439B0


OVERWRITE E8 07 9F 1A



So far I use REGEXREPLACE(B2,".{2}", "$0 ") to split B column and use FLATTEN()  and CONCATENATE() to get C column style .
Just wondering if there is efficient way to get C column.
Thx advance

You may try-
=TOCOL({INDEX("ADR $"&TOCOL(A1:A,1)),INDEX("OVERWRITE " & TOCOL(B1:B,1))},1)

If you need formatted text with space after two character then could try-
=TOCOL({INDEX("ADR $"&TOCOL(A1:A,1)),INDEX("OVERWRITE " & INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TOCOL(B1:B,1),".{2}", "$0 ")))},1)

Another option using MAP().
=TOCOL(MAP(TOCOL(A1:A,1),TOCOL(B1:B,1),LAMBDA(a,b,{"ADR $" & a,"OVERWRITE " & REGEXREPLACE(b,".{2}", "$0 ")})),1)



wonderful , it save my life . appreciate ur help :)

Try this Alternative solution
To achieve merging two columns using arrayformula try this solution.
Formula used.
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN({"ADR $" & FILTER(A2:A, A2:A <> ""),"OVERWRITE " & REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B <> ""), ".{2}", "$0 ")}))

The FILTER () for column A and B only includes rows where there’s actual data.
For the REGEXREPLACE() applies the space insertion logic only to non-empty rows.
ARRAYFORMULA processes all rows in the specified ranges, and FLATTEN ensures the outputs are stacked into a single column.
Sample Output

References

ARRAYFORMULA
FLATTEN
FILTER
REGEXREPLACE

